# import error for a lot of packages

Tags: python, pip, conda

Suddenly I can't import numpy or pip or a lot of other packages!
All return import error.

```
which python
/usr/bin/python

which pip
/home/user/anaconda2/bin/pip

python -V
Python 2.7.11+

pip -V
pip 8.0.2+gx2 from /home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages   (python 2.7)

conda search numpy 
numpy 1.10.4
```

How can I solve this issue?What can I try?What other information do you need from my side?

For example:

```
import pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pip

import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy


print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Comment: For a start, you might want to give us the full error including stack trace.

Comment: @PeterBrittain:I  updated , but as I am saying I can't import modules that already installed.

Comment: Sorry - my misunderstanding.  I suggest you print out sys.path and see if it's what you expect...

Comment: @PeterBrittain:It seems ok..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow reproduce the error, and if you use the python in /home/user/anaconda2/bin instead of /usr/bin, it should be fine

Comment: :By exporting python path?

Comment: @George, you can do that, or use full path to launch python, say /home/user/anaconda2/bin/python your_file.py